# how to get an element added from an ajax response

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the next code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('#dl-cat').mouseenter(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../control/Controlador.php",
        data: {lang: $('html').attr('lang'), cat: $(this).text(), prov: "none"},
        success: function(resp) {
            $(".og-grid").html(resp); 
        }
    });       
});

$(".og-grid li").on("mouseenter", function(){
    console.log("it exists");
});
```

});

Where the "og-grid" class is an "ul" tag and after the ajax response I put some html code like "li" tags, but when I program an event like "mouseenter" to the new added code It does not show me anything, as If It does not exist

Comment: you may need jquery's [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on) function to delegate the event to dynamic content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation model of `.on()` here since the `li` elements are dynamic

```
$(".og-grid").on("mouseenter", 'li', function(){
    console.log("it exists");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use event selectors. Rewrite your second event-listener as follows:

```
$(".og-grid").on("mouseenter", "li", function(){
   console.log("it exists");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the mouseenter event. Lets say I have a `<ul><ul>`. After 1 ajax call I have `<ul><li><ul>`, at this point of time you need to initialize the event on `<li>`. If you later have 2 `<li>`'s, you need to again initialize on the newly added one.